# How to force segment merge in Elasticsearch 1.6?

Tags: elasticsearch

I found in the [official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-forcemerge.html) how to force segment merge for Elasticsearch 2.3 but not for prior version , in particular 1.6.2 which I am using. So I would like to ask if there is a way to force segment merging for older versions of Elasticsearch .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to 2.x that was an [optimize API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/indices-optimize.html)

But be careful with it, running that on index with running index/update requests will hit performance hard.

Comment: sure, I am planning on optimizing when there is not much indexing search involved ;)